# Passing a pointer object within a function in a header file

Tags: c++, syntax

I am experincing an issue where the error is:
"2061 syntax error: identifier 'Person'

Enemy.h:

```
#include "person.h"

class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(string, string);

    void damage(Person*, Enemy*);
private:
    string name;
    string description;
};
```

Enemy.cpp:

```
Enemy::Enemy(string name, string description)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;
}

void Enemy::damage(Person* person, Enemy* enemy) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Person.h:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(string, string, int);

private:
    string name;
    string description;
    int health;

};
```

Person.cpp:

```
Person::Person(string name, string description, int health)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;
    this->health = health;
}
```

This line is causing the 206 error:

```
void damage(Person*, Enemy*);
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please provide complete error message and [mcve] of code.

Answer (score 0):

In Enemy.h you have a declaration `void damage(Person*, Enemy*);`, and in Enemy.cpp you have a definition `void Enemy::doDamage(Person* person, Enemy* enemy)`. The names `damage` and `doDamage` are different.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it, typo by accident - Still experincing the same issue though

Comment: In fact, I compiled your program and it ran flawlessly. I had to add `include <string>` and `std::string` instead of `string`.

Comment: that's really odd, it simply won't work for me at all. Running the exact same thing using include <string>

Comment: What type of compiler do you use? What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

The code in `Enemy.cpp` needs to know what the complete `Person` class looks like in order to access its members.  But, since the code in `Enemy.h` is using only `Person*` pointers, it just needs to know that the `Person` class exists but not what it looks like.

There are two ways to approach this:

Make `Enemy.h` include `Person.h`, and make `Enemy.cpp` include `Enemy.h`, eg:

Enemy.h:

```
#ifndef Enemy_H
#define Enemy_H

#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(std::string, std::string);

    void damage(Person*, Enemy*);
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
};

#endif
```

Enemy.cpp:

```
#include "Enemy.h"

Enemy::Enemy(std::string name, std::string description)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;
}

void Enemy::damage(Person* person, Enemy* enemy) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Person.h:

```
#ifndef Person_H
#define Person_H

#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string, std::string, int);

private:
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    int health;

};

#endif
```

Person.cpp:

```
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person(std::string name, std::string description, int health)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;
    this->health = health;
}
```

Alternatively, have `Enemy.h` *forward declare* `Person`, and then include `Person.h` in `Enemy.cpp`, eg:

Enemy.h:

```
#ifndef Enemy_H
#define Enemy_H

#include <string>

class Person;

class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy(std::string, std::string);

    void damage(Person*, Enemy*);
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
};

#endif
```

Enemy.cpp:

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Person.h"

Enemy::Enemy(std::string name, std::string description)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;
}

void Enemy::damage(Person* person, Enemy* enemy) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Person.h:

```
#ifndef Person_H
#define Person_H

#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string, std::string, int);

private:
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    int health;

};

#endif
```

Person.cpp:

```
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person(std::string name, std::string description, int health)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->description = description;
    this->health = health;
}
```